# Does it make sense to use pg_pconnect (php-fpm)

Tags: postgresql, php

I have about 11000 hits a second on 10 servers with php-fpm. I'm migrating to postgres from mysql, so my question is Does it make sense to use pg_**p**connect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use a dedicated connection pooler like [PgBouncer](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer).

Performance should be comparable to `pg_pconnect`, but PgBouncer [will allow to perform a cleanup](http://pgbouncer.projects.postgresql.org/doc/faq.html#_cleaning_prepared_statements_on_postgresql_8_3_and_newer) after an error in PHP code. `pg_pconnect` [will not automatically clean open transactions, locks, prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php) etc.

Comment: does it make sense to use pg_pconnect and pgbouncer together?

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense to use pg_pconnect and PgBouncer.

Answer (score 1):

Establishing a connection to a PostgreSQL server is expected to be significantly more expensive than to a MySQL server. This is due to different design choices of these databases in how they handle resource allocation and privilege separation between independent connections.

Therefore, for a website, it totally makes sense to reuse connections to PostgreSQL whenever possible.

The way generally recommended is not to use `pg_pconnect` but rather an external connection pooler like [pgBouncer](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer) or [pgPoolII](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pgpool-II) which are better suited for this task. When using PHP-FPM however, you already have a middleware that lets you control somehow the number of open connections through the fpm process manager options, so it may be good enough. You may consider setting `pm.max_requests` to a non-zero value to make sure that connections get cleaned up at a reasonable frequency and avoid keeping a pile of unused connections during off-peak hours.

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me Why it's not recommended to use pg_pconnect?

Comment: See @RichardHuxton's answer. Basically you end up coupling each apache process with a distinct open PG connection. That often means too much connections with too little control over them. But the fastcgi model mitigates that problem.

Comment: you can use pg_pconnect if you're using poolers (pgbouncer is my recommend) to keep the cost / time of those connections even lower.  Just avoid pg_pconnect directly to a pg server.

Answer (score 0):

Well, pg_pconnect will mean you have one connection per PHP backend, so it depends how many backends you have. With a traditional Apache mod-php setup it'd be a non-starter but you might get away with it.

The database server can handle hundreds of idle connections, but almost certainly grind to a halt if they all have queries being issued concurrently. I've seen a rule-of-thumb of no more than two connections per core - that's assuming I/O doesn't limit you first.

The common approach is to run a connection pooler like [pgbouncer](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer) and have php connect per-request. That reduces your connection overhead while keeping concurrency plausible.